# System.log and Exception.log size and maintenance?

Tags: magento, logging, cron

Our developer left a few weeks ago, so I have been attempting to get myself a little more acquainted with the systems and troubleshoot a few issues around the site.

I attempted to look at our log files in var/log/ before realizing that they are, erm, several GB each. Despite knowing almost nothing about how big an ideal log file should be, the fact that this file very handily crashed my computer seems like maybe it's too big. Before my computer crashed, I could see that there are records in the file that are over five months old.

**Is it safe to simply delete system.log and exception.log?**

When I search for this, I get a lot of results related to Log Cleaning...

In Magento there are settings under System to turn on 'Log Cleaning', but I suspect that has nothing to do with these two log files because a) it looks like it is set to clear it daily and b) cron is set up. If I am incorrect about that, please let me know so I can look into why that is not working correctly.

Comment: did you try resolve errors that log-files would be clear everyday? if cron doesn't clear logs you can always add `rm -rf var/log/*` to cron.sh

Comment: I am a little hesitant to change any server settings that I absolutely do not have to, but I will mention it to our new developer whenever we hire one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You guessed correctly.  The log cleaning settings refer to tables of logs in the database.  The files in `var/log/` are safe to delete, as are most files in `var/`.  If you do not need these files then it is simplest to turn them off from *System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings*.

However, if you do think you want some logs just in case then learn how to use [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) on your server, it can compress files and delete the oldest for you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to use logrotate. It works like a charm! Because I am far from anything resembling a sysadmin, I found this [Magento-specific article about setting up logrotate](http://briansnelson.com/Magento_Log_Rotate_with_logrotate) to be helpful.

Comment: You can delete most files in the `var/` folder but if you delete the `var/package/` folder, the Magneto connect manager won't find any of the packages already installed.

Comment: That is an excellent point.  The connect manager won't be able to uninstall or upgrade those extensions and you'll effectively be stuck with them as is.